# Upload File Component with ReactJS

Tags: jquery, ajax, reactjs

I've been looking everywhere for some help on making a component to help manage uploading files from within React to an endpoint I have setup.

I've tried numerous options, including integrating [filedropjs](http://filedropjs.org). I decided against it because I don't have control over the elements it sets up in the DOM with the `new FileDrop('zone', options);`

This is what I have so far:

```
module.exports =  React.createClass({
displayName: "Upload",
handleChange: function(e){

    formData = this.refs.uploadForm.getDOMNode();

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'http://example.com',
        type : 'POST',
        xhr: function(){
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if(myXhr.upload){
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction, false);
            }
            return myXhr;
        },
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });

},
render: function(){

        return (
            <form ref="uploadForm" className="uploader" encType="multipart/form-data" onChange={this.handleChange}>
                <input ref="file" type="file" name="file" className="upload-file"/>
            </form>
        );
   }

 });



},
render: function(){

    console.log(this.props.content);

    if(this.props.content != ""){
        return (
            <img src={this.props.content} />
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <form className="uploader" encType="multipart/form-data" onChange={this.handleChange}>
                <input ref="file" type="file" name="file" className="upload-file"/>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
});
```

If someone could just point me in the right direction I would send some virtual hugs. I've been working on this quite extensively. I feel like I'm close, but not quite there.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if you can use this or not -- possibly not -- but just in case: http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php

Comment: how about something as simple as this http://jsbin.com/qulozo/2 ?

Comment: I put together a simple blog post that outlines simple steps to take to upload an image using React with Node.js and also upload to S3: http://www.benrlodge.com/blog/post/image-uploading-with-reactjs-nodejs-and-aws-s3

Comment: @Dan            Can you post the solution you ended up choosing?  Thank you

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I worked on this quite a while as well.  This what I came up with.

A `Dropzone` component, coupled with using [superagent](https://github.com/KyleAMathews/superagent-bluebird-promise).

```
// based on https://github.com/paramaggarwal/react-dropzone, adds image preview    
const React = require('react');
const _ = require('lodash');

var Dropzone = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      isDragActive: false
    }
  },

  propTypes: {
    onDrop: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    size: React.PropTypes.number,
    style: React.PropTypes.object
  },

  onDragLeave: function(e) {
    this.setState({
      isDragActive: false
    });
  },

  onDragOver: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';

    this.setState({
      isDragActive: true
    });
  },

  onDrop: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({
      isDragActive: false
    });

    var files;
    if (e.dataTransfer) {
      files = e.dataTransfer.files;
    } else if (e.target) {
      files = e.target.files;
    }

    _.each(files, this._createPreview);
  },

  onClick: function () {
    this.refs.fileInput.getDOMNode().click();
  },

  _createPreview: function(file){
    var self = this
      , newFile
      , reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = function(e){
      newFile = {file:file, imageUrl:e.target.result};
      if (self.props.onDrop) {
        self.props.onDrop(newFile);
      }
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  },

  render: function() {

    var className = 'dropzone';
    if (this.state.isDragActive) {
      className += ' active';
    };

    var style = {
      width: this.props.size || 100,
      height: this.props.size || 100,
      borderStyle: this.state.isDragActive ? 'solid' : 'dashed'
    };

    return (
      <div className={className} onClick={this.onClick} onDragLeave={this.onDragLeave} onDragOver={this.onDragOver} onDrop={this.onDrop}>
        <input style={{display: 'none' }} type='file' multiple ref='fileInput' onChange={this.onDrop} />
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }

});

module.exports = Dropzone
```

Using the `Dropzone`.

```
    <Dropzone onDrop={this.onAddFile}>
      <p>Drag &amp; drop files here or click here to browse for files.</p>
    </Dropzone>
```

When a file is added to the drop zone, add it to your list of files to upload.  I add it to my flux store.

```
  onAddFile: function(res){
    var newFile = {
      id:uuid(),
      name:res.file.name,
      size: res.file.size,
      altText:'',
      caption: '',
      file:res.file,
      url:res.imageUrl
    };
    this.executeAction(newImageAction, newFile);
  }
```

You can use the imageUrl to display a preview of the file.

```
  <img ref="img" src={this.state.imageUrl} width="120" height="120"/>
```

To upload the files, get the list of files and send them through superagent.  I'm using flux, so I get the list of images from that store.

```
  request = require('superagent-bluebird-promise')
  Promise = require('bluebird')

    upload: function(){
      var images = this.getStore(ProductsStore).getNewImages();
      var csrf = this.getStore(ApplicationStore).token;
      var url = '/images/upload';
      var requests = [];
      var promise;
      var self = this;
      _.each(images, function(img){

        if(!img.name || img.name.length == 0) return;

        promise = request
          .post(url)
          .field('name', img.name)
          .field('altText', img.altText)
          .field('caption', img.caption)
          .field('size', img.size)
          .attach('image', img.file, img.file.name)
          .set('Accept', 'application/json')
          .set('x-csrf-token', csrf)
          .on('progress', function(e) {
            console.log('Percentage done: ', e.percent);
          })
          .promise()
          .then(function(res){
            var newImg = res.body.result;
            newImg.id = img.id;
            self.executeAction(savedNewImageAction, newImg);
          })
          .catch(function(err){
            self.executeAction(savedNewImageErrorAction, err.res.body.errors);
          });
        requests.push(promise);
      });

      Promise
        .all(requests)
        .then(function(){
          console.log('all done');
        })
        .catch(function(){
          console.log('done with errors');
        });
    }
```

Comment: What is `this.executeAction(newImageAction, newFile);` doing? Shouldn't newImageAction be replaced by something? Also, where should the final code block go - in the Dropzone component or the Store?

Comment: @frogbandit `this.executeAction()` is from the Fluxible framework by Yahoo. http://fluxible.io - what final code block are you referring to?

Comment: @JoeMcBride Gotcha. What is it supposed to do though? It's always giving me `newImageAction is not defined`

Comment: The codeblock I'm referring to (my section question) is everything from `request = require('superagent-bluebird-promise')` down.

Comment: @frogbandit The second codeblock is example code to upload a list of images to a server using `superagent`.  `newImageAction` is a flux action.  You don't have to use `executeAction` unless you are using fluxible.  You can use the object created, `newFile`, and do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 28):

This may help

```
var FormUpload = React.createClass({
    uploadFile: function (e) {
        var fd = new FormData();    
        fd.append('file', this.refs.file.getDOMNode().files[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:51218/api/Values/UploadFile',
            data: fd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            } 
        });
        e.preventDefault()
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>                
               <form ref="uploadForm" className="uploader" encType="multipart/form-data" >
                   <input ref="file" type="file" name="file" className="upload-file"/>
                   <input type="button" ref="button" value="Upload" onClick={this.uploadFile} />
               </form>                
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

borrowed from here [How to send FormData objects with Ajax-requests in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery)

Comment: This is aweseome! Works perfectly across all browsers i could think of. Thanks!

Comment: As of React 0.14 "this.refs.file" *is* the DOM node, so getDOMNode is deprecated.  The fd.append line becomes: <code>fd.append('file', this.refs.file.files[0]);</code>

Answer (score 2):

I was faced with the task of getting that facebook or gmail-like behavior where your drop target highlights as soon as the user begins dragging a file anywhere over the window. There was no off-the-shelf React drag and drop solution that I could find. So, I made one.

It is meant to be bare-bones, supplying you with a base to customize and style as your own. It provides many hooks to enable you to do this. But there is also a demo that gives you an example to go off of.

Check it out: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-file-drop

Demo: http://sarink.github.io/react-file-drop/demo/

Comment: @KabirSarin react-file-drop has file remove feature ?

Comment: @KabirSarin Also is it possible to customize the file type I want to accept ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a Dropzone npm package for this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dropzone

Comment: http://okonet.ru/react-dropzone/ accepts only images ? I need file drag and drop with specifed type. is it possible ?