# Basic file uploads with Node & React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I've built a React App to teach myself `React` and `Node.js`. I'm using the boilerplate provided by Facebook called [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) which uses `Webpack` to bundle the App. I'm at the point now where i'm trying to create an upload file function within the app. I stumbled upon something called [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) which when used with Express enables for fairly straight forward file uploads. I plan to use this and express for the file upload part of my app. Here is the code below with what i'm trying to achieve:

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import testupload from './testupload/testupload';
var App = React.createClass({
        testUpload(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            testupload();
        },
        render() {
            return (<div className="outer-most-container">   
               <form encType='multipart/form-data'>
                    <input type="file" method="post"/>
                    <button type="submit" onClick={this.testUpload}>submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>)
        }) export default App;
```

testupload.js:

```
var express = require('express')
var multer = require('multer')
var upload = multer({
    dest: 'uploads/'
})
var app = express()
var testupload = function() {
    app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function(req, res, next) {})
    app.post('/photos/upload', upload.array('photos', 12), function(req, res, next) {})
    var cpUpload = upload.fields([{
        name: 'avatar',
        maxCount: 1
    }, {
        name: 'gallery',
        maxCount: 8
    }])
    app.post('/cool-profile', cpUpload, function(req, res, next) {})
}
export default testupload;
```

I'm used to working with PHP when it comes to file uploads so my logic here is when you click the button to submit there is a prevent of the default event, then it executes the `testupload` function which was imported from another script. The error i'm getting at the moment is

> Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

which is in the `request.js` so says the browser console. Not sure if my approach is the correct logic here so a push in the right direction would really help. What i'm finding particularly tough is determining where exactly the crossover from the front end JS to the server side JS is and if i'm attempting to execute the server side JS in the right place. I haven't found any good tutorials online on how to do this hence why i'm posting on here. Please let me know if anything is unclear as i'm fairly new to React & `Node.js` so I appreciate some of the code above might not be very logical in some parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you're trying to import your Node code right in your React component. What you'll want to do is move your server code into another project, and run a server. you would add an `app.listen(port, ....)` to your server code, where `port` is your choice (create-react-app runs on 3000 by default, so pick something else). then, have your file upload code in your React application `POST` the files to your specified endpoints

Comment: Could you give me a brief example of how the post would look? Where i'm struggling is the part where you link the front end to the server side. Your bit about hosting a server elsewhere makes sense, can you recommend a good framework for this - like would Express for example be a good option?

Comment: Yes, Express can be a good choice, and what I've done in the past when I want to keep the stack entirely Javascript. Check out this answer for what your frontend code could look like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28750489/upload-file-component-with-reactjs

Comment: one more thing, in the top of my app.js file when I use things like 'import' React from 'react'; - is this Node.js?

Comment: no, that's used to import other modules.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import