# reactjs mongodb - how to upload a file and save in mongodb document

Tags: reactjs

How to upload a file and save into a mongodb document. In my form, i have two button 1. for upload a file and 2. for save the document. But am not sure about the flow here. Am using reactjs as my frontend. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDb provides you the option to store images.
MongoGridFS.

Study more about [MongoGridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/)

On click of a button, make a call to upload the image uploaded and save the image in the mongoDB.

You just need to send form data through ajax and take the save functionality in the back end

[Upload Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28750489/upload-file-component-with-reactjs)